# Onclick jQuery is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, onclick

I have a situation i am generating dynamic html using jQuery like

```
var list_of_addressbook_entries = {};
var filter = []
function save(){
    var user = $("#addressbook_user").val();
    var desg = $("#desg").val();
    var ahtml='<div  id ="user_'+user+'"  class="addr_list" style=" font-size: 30px;display:block; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% peachpuff;margin:1px 1px 1px 1px ;">'
    ahtml = ahtml + '<span style="display: block; float: left; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px 24px 2px 21px;" >'+user+'</span>'
    if(desg == 'M'){
        ahtml = ahtml + '<span style="display: block; float: left; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px 24px 2px 21px;">Moderator</span>'
    }
    else{
        ahtml = ahtml + '<span style="display: block; float: left; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px 24px 2px 21px;">Attendee</span>'
    }
    ahtml = ahtml + '<div  onclick="remove_video(\''+user+'\')"><span ><img src="/UI/user/img/delet.jpeg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"  /> </span></div></div>'
    var ua = "'"+user+"'"; 
    filter.push(ua);
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",  
        url: "<?php echo SITE_URL;?>/UI/user/filterbox.php",  
        data: "list="+ filter+"&Where=addressbook" ,
        success: function(json){ 
               $('#addorguser').html(json);
              // if(!json.error) location.reload(true);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            alert(json);
        }

    });





    $("#organization").append(ahtml);



}
    function remove_video(user){
        alert(user);
        $("#user_"+user).hide();
    }
```

After calling the save() i am appending dynamically generated html to a div there is a remove_video function i also defined in the dynamic html .

But when i am clicking on dynamic div to remove the div the remove_video function is not getting called .

I am also not getting any error .

Help me plz .

**Updated Html **

```
    <div id="organization" name="organization">
    </div>

                 <div>Address Book</div><br>

                <div id="box1">
                        <?php
                        if (isset($_SESSION["user_name"])){
                            $get_user_name = $_SESSION["user_name"];
                            ?>
                <div id="addorguser" style="display: block; float: left;">
                        <select  id ="addressbook_user" name="addressboook_user">
                        <?php 

                            $asql = "SELECT *  from demo_addressbook WHERE user_created_id IN(SELECT id FROM demo_user WHERE user_name = '$get_user_name') AND type = 1 ";                      
                        //  $result = mysql_query($query);
                        //  mysql_real_escape_string($asql);
                            $aresult    = mysql_query($asql) or die (mysql_error());
                            while($arow_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($aresult)){
                                ?>                      
                                <option value="<?php echo $arow_list['guest_name']; ?>"><?php echo $arow_list['guest_name']; ?></option>
                                <?php                                   
                            }
                                ?>
                            </select>

                    </div>      
                            <select name="desg" id="desg">
                            <option value="A">Attendee</option>
                            <option value="M">Moderator</option>

                            </select>
                            <input type="button" id ="aadd" onclick="save()" name="button" value="Add"/>
                </div>

                <?php 
                        }
                ?>
```

Comment: Big mess of PHP + MySQL + HTML + JS + inline CSS: consider learning about separation of concerns before getting mad.

Comment: suggest me some solution or link

Comment: Start from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639622/separation-of-concerns-mvc-why

Answer (score 0):

Try this exemple:

```
$('#aadd').on('click', function(e){
     alert('Click');
});
```

or this one

```
$('#aadd').click(function(e){
     alert('Click');
});
```

Comment: I can't do the id are varying

Comment: use some CSS class class="submit-button"