# Pull data from array to <div>

Tags: html, css, arrays

I have a wordpress site where I am trying to use an array to apply css classes to  elements.

My array is as follows:

```
<?php

$classes = array(
    0 => 'highlight-color-1',
    1 => 'highlight-color-2',
    2 => 'highlight-color-3',
    3 => 'highlight-color-4');

?>
```

I then have the following html on four different elements:

```
<div class="q element element--content ******">
```

I need to loop through the array and apply the css class to replace the ***** so that i get something like this

```
<div class="q element element--content highlight-color-4"></div>
<div class="q element element--content highlight-color-3"></div>
<div class="q element element--content highlight-color-2"></div>
<div class="q element element--content highlight-color-1"></div>
```

Section of the code for context

```
// Displays Post Detail

if( $WP_Query->post_count > 0) :?>



<ul class="faq">

<?php while ($WP_Query->have_posts()) : $WP_Query->the_post();

    $classes = array(

    0 => 'highlight-color-1',
    1 => 'highlight-color-2',
    2 => 'highlight-color-3',
    3 => 'highlight-color-4');      

    ?>

    <div class="q element element--content ">

    <div class="faq_plus"><img src="http://drbarbaramariposa.com/wp-content/plugins/accordion-faq-plugin/plus.png" ></div>

    <div class="faq_title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>

    </div>

    <li class="a">

        <?php if ( function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') && has_post_thumbnail() ) {

                the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); 

              }

        ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

    </li>

<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>

</ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help much appreciated.

CHRIS

Comment: Alternatively, you can reference which part you want with `<?php print $classes[0];?>` or `<?php print $classes[1];?>` etc.

Comment: Ok, so how do you (or I) know which class elements belong in which `div`? What's the relationship?

Comment: There is no specific relationship between the div and the css class that gets applied as it is just a colour. If the page generated 6 posts it should loop through the array to get colour 1, colour 2, colour 3, colour 4, colour 1, colour 2. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi Chris, I have updated my answer below for you.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no specific relationship between the div and the css class
>   that gets applied as it is just a colour. If the page generated 6
>   posts it should loop through the array to get colour 1, colour 2,
>   colour 3, colour 4, colour 1, colour 2. Does that make sense?

You want to use a rolling counter that counts up each array key value in a looping structure based on the while loop iteration. On the basis that you want every `******` changed to the array element values mentioned, you can structure it like this:

```
<?php 
$classes = array(
    0 => 'highlight-color-1',
    1 => 'highlight-color-2',
    2 => 'highlight-color-3',
    3 => 'highlight-color-4');
$counter = 0; 
$counterMax = count($classes); 

while ($WP_Query->have_posts()) : $WP_Query->the_post();
if($counter >= $counterMax) {
    $counter = 0;
}       
print "<div class='q element element--content ".$classes[$counter]."'>
 $counter++;
    ?>

    ...
<?php $i++; endwhile; 
 unset($counter, $counterMax);
 ?>
```

What is that `$i++` doing?

What this does is seta counter to +1 ech time the while loop runs and the counter is a reference key to the array element, if the counter goes too large then it is reset to zero.

The assumption made on this code is that the array has no gaps and that each and every element as stated wants one value from the `$classes` array.

Comment: Thanks Martin - it is the more complex foreach structure that i need to achieve. I should have mentioned it is a wordpress site so the div elements are created dynamically for each 'post'

Comment: @ChrisDavies you can edit them at the point of creation or use [CSS nth-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/) or similar selectors in your style sheet. Can you update your question to give the context that it's a WP site and if you can access the point where the divs are generated by the code (the logic point to insert the array elements)?

Answer (score 0):

its very simple

```
foreach($classes as $class){ ?>
    <div class="q element element--content <?php echo $class?>></div>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Flipping in and out of PHP code blocks like that looks a mess, is inefficient and is not good practise. I've worked with code that does this on a page wide scale and it's terrible to work with.

Comment: @Martin what's the preferred alternative? When you have a lot of HTML and PHP on one page how can you format it so it doesn't look like a cluster-fuck?

Comment: I can't find a good all-in-one guide that describes it in detail but basically you should be using a [separation of concerns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639622/separation-of-concerns-mvc-why) approach where all the data to render in the browser is built in the PHP *before anything is output to the browser itself*, so you have `<?php $codestuff ... $output = "output code ".$code; ?>` and then directly after it you then have the HTML output. so you have `<html><head><body><php print $output;?></body></html>` which is cleaner and simpler data blocks. @EdmundReed

Comment: @EdmundReed also look up [the MVC approach](http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/)

Comment: @EdmundReed as a general rule at the top of a PHP page sort out all your PHP programming so that you only have at most a handful of clear variables of string data you want to show the end user, to then plug into the HTML code that appears below the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) in a foreach loop.

```
foreach ($classes as $c){
    echo str_replace("******",$c,"<div class='q element element--content ******'></div>");
}
```